# How to take to cursor to the end of the line (Without disturbing the content of the line) after we use the escape sequence \r in C?

Tags: c, escaping

I want to know that how we can take the cursor to the end of the line without over writing the contents of the line:

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("This is a test line\r");
    printf("###"); // Cursor moves to start of the line and over writes the content
    printf("I want to print this at the end of the line"); // I want to take the cursor to the end of the line and then print this
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
###I want to print this at the end of the line
```

But I want the output to be like this (by cursor movement, not by simply using this in `printf()`):

```
###s is a test lineI want to print this at the end of the line
```

What's the method to do this in C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [ANSI escape sequences](http://rrbrandt.dee.ufcg.edu.br/en/docs/ansi/cursor) works for me

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("One Two Three\x1b[s\r");
    //                   ^^^^^^      ESC[s ==> save cursor position
    printf("###\x1b[u");
    //         ^^^^^^                ESC[u ==> restore cursor position
    printf("FOUR FIVE SIX\n");
}
```

Apparent output

```
### Two ThreeFOUR FIVE SIX
```

Comment: This means that there is not direct escape sequence to jump to the end of the line. We first need to store the cursor position.. Also please tell me about the portability of the program which I will create using this..

Comment: All bets are off if the user redirects output: `executable >file.txt`

Comment: please can you elaborate what you said. I didn't got it

Comment: ANSI escape sequences are a function of the terminal driver. I don't really know about portability among different OSes and configurations.

Comment: Okay bro... I got what I want to know from your answer. Thanks :-)

Comment: Can we use two such escape sequences to store two positions of the cursor??

Comment: No, just one. Or you could use [ncurses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses) for example, which has that functionality and much, **much** more.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
        
        int main()
        {
            printf("This is a test line");
            printf("I want to print this at the end of the line\r");
            printf("###");
             
            return 0;
        }
```

Output:
`###s is a test lineI want to print this at the end of the line`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).